# nginx phpmyadmin 404

Tags: nginx, subdomain, http-status-code-404

I am trying to install phpmyadmin on my nginx web server. I installed phpmyadmin without a problem. I created subdomain for it. For security reasons I didnt call my subdomain "phpmyadmin" i used a different name. Then I used this config for my subdomain

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name myphpmyadminsubdomain.domain.com;
    access_log off;
    error_log /srv/www/myphpmyadminsubdomain/error.log;

    location / {
                root   /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
                index  index.php;
                }

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
#   fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass php;
}

location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}
      }
```

Then I enabled it like this;

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/myphpmyadminsubdomain /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myphpmyadminsubdomain
```

I have restarted the nginx and go to myphpmyadminsubdomain.domain.com and it is giving me nginx 404 Not Found error.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I had this same issue but forgot the solution. Try hard coding the  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; line with your document root.

Comment: tried, it didint work sorry =/

Comment: Do the static files (eg /robots.txt) work? Is there anything in the nginx error log?

Comment: the error is this `2011/11/18 16:53:29 [error] 3955#0: *1 directory index of "/srv/www/mysubdomain/" is forbidden, client: XX.XX.XXX.XXX, server: mysubdomain.domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "mysubdomain.domain.com"`

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue then.  Check that your nginx user can reach those areas.  I temp. set the user to have a bash shell and then use "su -" to that user and navigate to the files required.

Comment: tried but no luck =/

Answer (score 1):

This is my configuration

```
server {
    listen 80; ## listen for ipv4
    server_name pma.example.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/pma.access.log;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/pma.error.log;
    root /server/phpmyadmin/phpMyAdmin-3.4.2-all-languages;

    location / {
            index index.php index.html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
            fastcgi_pass php;
    }

}
```

The root should be changed to `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` and the `fastcgi_params` should be changed appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually a path problem. In nginx.conf set

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /absolute/path/to/server/root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Note that there is no slash after the last dir in the path. Secondly, fastcgi_pass to either a socket or a local URL.

Are you chrooting your php-cgi? Then all paths have to be relative to that chroot.